# Size$\alpha$ test when likelihood is constant

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I have to find the uniformly most powerful size $\alpha$ test for the following pdf-
$$f(x|\theta) = exp\{-(x-\theta)\}$$ $x>\theta$

The pdf is 0 for $x\leq\theta$ ,
Null hypothesis is $\theta = \theta_0$ and alternate is $\theta =\theta_1$.
 I am given an i.i.d. sample from the above pdf. I was trying to apply the Neyman pearson lemma but the relative likelihood is constant so I don’t know how to find the UMP size $\alpha$ test, can someone please provide the solution.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420636/how-to-most-powerful-test-of-size-alpha.

Comment: As per our [help/on-topic] please choose one best location for your questions.

Comment: Yes, I’ll keep it in mind next time